# Pending Monthly SQL Counts

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

The below query returns accurate info, I just haven't had any luck trying to make this:

1) More dynamic so I'm not repeating the same line of code every month

2) Formatted differently, so just 2 columns of month + year are needed to view pending counts by field1 + field2

Example code (basically, sum when (OPEN date is before/on the last day of the month) and (CLOSE date comes after the month OR it's still opened)

```
SELECT
SUM(CAST(case when OPENDATE <= '2014-11-30 23:59:59' 
      and ((CLOSED >= '2014-12-01')  
            or (CLOSED is null)) then '1' else '0' end as int)) Nov14    
,SUM(CAST(case when OPENDATE <= '2014-12-31 23:59:59'
      and ((CLOSED >= '2015-01-01')  
            or (CLOSED is null)) then '1' else '0' end as int)) Dec14          
,SUM(CAST(case when OPENDATE <= '2015-01-30 23:59:59'
      and ((CLOSED >= '2015-02-01')  
            or (CLOSED is null)) then '1' else '0' end as int)) Jan15 
,FIELD1,FIELD2 
FROM T 
GROUP BY FIELD1,FIELD2
```

Results:

```
FIELD1 FIELD2 NOV14  DEC14  JAN15
A      A      2      5      7
A      B      6      8      4
C      A      5      6      5
```

…

Instead of:

```
COUNT   FIELD1 FIELD2  MO   YR
14      A      A       12   2014      
18      A      B       12   2014             
16      C      A       1    2015
```

...

Is there a way to get this in one shot?  Sorry if this is a repeat topic, I've looked at some boards and they've helped me get closing counts.. but using a range between two date fields, I haven't had any luck.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you  add more sample input and required output? and generate a `sqlfiddle.com`demo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to use a [table of numbers](http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-numbers-table.html) or [calendar table](http://web.archive.org/web/20070611150639/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html).
In the code below the table `Numbers` has a column `Number`, which contains integer numbers starting from 1. There are many ways to [generate such table](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1).
You can do it on the fly, or have the actual table. I personally have such table in the database with 100,000 rows.

The first `CROSS APPLY` effectively creates a column `CurrentMonth`, so that I don't have to repeat the call to `DATEADD` many times later.

Second `CROSS APPLY` is your query that you want to run for each month. It can be as complicated as needed, it can return more than one row if needed.

```
-- Start and end dates should be the first day of the month
DECLARE @StartDate date = '20141201';
DECLARE @EndDate   date = '20150201';

SELECT
    CurrentMonth
    ,FIELD1
    ,FIELD2
    ,Counts
FROM
    Numbers
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT DATEADD(month, Numbers.Number-1, @StartDate) AS CurrentMonth
    ) AS CA_Month
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            FIELD1
            ,FIELD2
            ,COUNT(*) AS Counts
        FROM T
        WHERE
            OPENDATE < CurrentMonth
            AND (CLOSED >= CurrentMonth OR CLOSED IS NULL)
        GROUP BY
            FIELD1
            ,FIELD2
    ) AS CA
WHERE
    Numbers.Number < DATEDIFF(month, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1
;
```

If you provide a table with sample data and expected output, I could verify that the query produces correct results.

The solution is written in SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
SELECT
FIELD1,FIELD2,datepart(month, OPENDATE), datepart(year, OPENDATE), sum(1)
FROM T 
GROUP BY FIELD1,FIELD2, datepart(month, OPENDATE), datepart(year, OPENDATE)
```

But this of course is just based on OPENDATE, if you need to have the same thing calculated into several months, that's going to be more difficult, and you'll probably need a calendar "table" that you'll have to cross apply with this data.